# gnu software in company

Tags: licensing, gnu

is it "legal" to use GNU-Code in a software project developed from a company for internal use only.

So here is no distribution out of the company.

nobody can force the company to publish their code?

Comment: Read [this](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) to know what is in the GNU.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The licenses don't require you to publish your software at all.